# How to implement services that relate to third party bundles?

Tags: php, symfony, service, vichuploaderbundle

There is one thing that I dont want to miss about Symfony, because I thought I could not understood  so good. Could you help me??  I'll put the bundle `VichUploaderBundle` as example, but in others the same is happened.

The documentation says [how to create a custom directory](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/directory_namer/howto/create_a_custom_directory_namer.md), but in my case I would like to relate to `id` from  `news`. 
Example directory: upload/news/:news_id/image.jpg

What I understand with this is that i have to create two diferent services, one for `upload_destination` and other for `directory_namer`, I´m right?

config.yml

```
vich_uploader: 
    # ... 
    mappings: 
    product_image: 
    upload_destination: news_image 
    directory_namer:    my.directory_namer.news
```

But how I can do it? If I follow the documentation from Symfony, I should create this way 
[the Synfony services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).

What steps should I follow? I think create a class in my  `Newsbundle` and assign it as ´services`. Its ok?

How I could do a capture in the `class` that i have been created as `service` the `news_id`? and the fine `image_name` to save it in the `database`? and then save the `custom directory` also?

This is for me a very important thing to learn, because I think knowing this helps me understand the others bundles and how to aplicate them.

In summary:

How do I save to a custom directory with the id of the news and how rename the image with the id of the news?

I hope you can help me.

thanks, Carlos.

Comment: I don't understand the question but I think you might be looking for semantic configuration: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ways to interact with an external bundle are multiple :

- Use Events triggered by the bundle
- Configuration override
- Declare services which will be manipulated by the bundle (like in your example)
- Override the bundle - some bundles put some classes path into their configuration, you can use your own classe by override this.

I never used **VichUploaderBundle**, but after a quick look into his documentation, it seems that your service named "my.directory_namer.news" should implement the **DirectoryNamerInterface** (https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Naming/DirectoryNamerInterface.php)

Then, you can define the "directoryName" method imposed by the interface and put your logic into it to build the directory's name from the object (the news).

Hope this will help you.

Best regards,
J